# Authenticate user in Global Catalog

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-authentication

I need to authenticate user's Windows credentials, given a userId, domain and password. Our Active Directory contains multiple domains, some which we can list using the following code:

```
var domains = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains;
```

However, we also have users that belong to domains outside the forest. They are however accessible to me from the Global Catalog (GC). Below code allows me to get a directory entry for a userid.

```
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry globalCatalogDE = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("GC://DC=nsroot,DC=net");
var ds = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(globalCatalogDE);
ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + userId + "))";
System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry userDE = ds.FindAll()[0].GetDirectoryEntry();
```

How do I authenticate a user that belongs to a domain I can not directly access but is available to me in the GC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't authenticate a user by looking in the Global Catalog, it's for searching only (any attribute marked with the `isMemberOfPartialAttributeSet` in the schema for each domain is replicated to the GC).

Passwords are not replicated to it; otherwise you would have the passwords of all users in the entire forrest on each domain controller which would be very bad from a security and replication standpoint. You need to establish a connection to the domain where the user's credentials are stored (ie you need access to LDAP ports 389 or 636).

Comment: Sounds reasonable enough for me to mark as an answer even if it didn't solve my problem.