# How can I implement forms-based LDAP authentication against a multi-domain AD?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, active-directory, ldap

Apologies in advance for my deficiency in AD terminology but I'm an ASP.NET developer and don't understand Active Directory well.

We've been asked to implemented a standard LDAP authentication against an on-premise AD. The AD has multiple domains. In the Windows 'Find Users, Contacts and Groups' dialogue the 'In' dropdown lists a parent domain as 'domain.net' and a series of sub-domains nested under it as 'sub1.domain.net', 'sub2.domain.net' etc.

Initially I was using a standard LDAP connection string like `LDAP://dcserver/DC=domain,DC=net` and finding that I could authenticate users on the domain.net domain, but not on any of the sub-domains.

Having done some research I see that my situation is similar to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829727/authenticate-user-in-global-catalog) where it appears these sub-domains are outside the forest but accessible to me from the Global Catalog (GC). I've tested this using the [ldp.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794810(v=ws.10).aspx) tool. If I connect ldp.exe using the GC port (3268) I can return users on those sub-domains.

Given this, I understand that with the current AD setup I cannot implement a standard LDAP authentication as required. I presume I therefore need to either:

1. Customise the application's authentication mechanism to authenticate against more than one domain, or
2. Instruct my client around how to update their AD configuration so it supports my needs.

I'm not even sure if (1) is possible, but in any case (2) is preferable since actually this authentication is part of a CMS implementation which would be a lot of work to customise in this regard. So with your help I'd like to compile a set of instructions to get this sorted out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to use the LDAP connection string `GC://DC=domain,DC=net`? Or `LDAP://DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=net`?

Comment: I think instead of using ´dcserver´ you shoud try to connect using specific subdomain as LDAP://sub1.domain.net/DC=sub1,DC=domain,DC=net, this all however depends on the setup of your AD.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. However what I need, if at all possible, is one connection string that can interrogate all those sub-domains. As for using a GC protocol, my understanding is that GC cannot be used for authentication.

Comment: I was able to get authentication to work using GC, have you tried something like this `ldap://dcserver:3268/DC=domain,DC=net` or `ldaps://dcserver:3269/DC=domain,DC=net`?  I think it would depend on how the windows admins have the GC setup at your company.